# Loop through directories and look for directory name in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a truncate system.

I want to permanently delete whole directories that are older than 14 days. The directories are named with dates in this format: dd-mm-yyyy

```
$path = "sites/sitename/.trash/";
$lastDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+14 days"));
```

Is what I currently have. Which get the date in 14 days. I would like now to loop through the directories and check their names if they match $lastDate or are over that date.

So it would be something like:

```
if($pathName >= $lastDate) { $this->deleteDir($pathName); }
```

How can I do this? Looping through and check for their directories names, inside my $path (.trash/ directory where all the other date-named directories exists)

Comment: You can just execute a `find` command. Or are you not on a Unix system? Otherwise `find /the/root -depth -daystart -mtime +14 -exec rm -rf {} \;` will do what you want

Comment: Yes i do not want to do that, i would like to just do this inside a php file that will be a cronjob script.

Comment: A cron job and you want to do that in PHP?? You could just use the find command directly in cron! Why use PHP at all?

Comment: Please, I created this question because I wish it to do it this way, not to argue/discuss options for an alternative way. I do not have access to the command for php on the server eitherway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a combination of [opendir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php), [closedir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.closedir.php) and [readdir()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)

```
<?php
$path = "d:/";
$dirHandler = opendir($path);

while( $currentDir = readdir( $dirHandler ) )
{
    if( in_array($currentDir, array('.', '..')) ) continue;//skip current and parent dir

    if( is_dir( $path . $currentDir))
    {
        echo $path . $currentDir . "<br />";
        //do your process here
    }
}

closedir($dirHandler);
```